# Changing Spline Evaluation Rate in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I would like the ball to accelerate in the begging and end of the spline evaluation and deaccelerate in the middle, while it is in the air. Is there a way to change the default location?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can evaluate the time at some interpolation whose derivative represents the velocity of the animation. In your case, such interpolation would look like:

[image: Node Tree]

Also, don't keyframe your nodes, try to use the *Time Info* and *Animate Float* nodes instead. Finally, you don't need the *Mesh Info* node, the same output is in the *Mesh Object Info* node.